# Como aumentar o nível de otimização de imagens usando o Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulpjs

Tenho uma tarefa e gostaria de saber como faço para melhorar a otimização da imagem? Segue meu script abaixo:

```
gulp.task(
    'build-img',
    () =>
    gulp.src('assets/img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin( {
            interlaced: true,
            progressive: true,
            optimizationLevel: 2,
            svgoPlugins: [{
                removeViewBox: true
            }]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
)
```

Eu li na documentação que vai de 0 - 10 i nível. Mas as otimizações se mentém estáticas.